# Is Precaching with Workbox mandatory for PWA?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

I added a few `workbox.routing.registerRoute` using `staleWhileRevalidate` to my app and so far it has passed most lighthouse tests under PWA.  I am not currently using Precaching at all. My question is, is it mandatory?  What am I missing without Precaching? `workbox.routing.registerRoute` is already caching everything I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nothing is *mandatory*. :-)

Using stale-while-revalidate for all of your assets, as well as for your HTML, is definitely a legitimate approach. It means that you don't have to do anything special as part of your build process, for instance, which could be nice in some scenarios.

Whenever you're using a strategy that reads from the cache, whether it's via precaching or stale-while-revalidate, there's going to be some sort of revalidation step to ensure that you don't end up serving out of date responses indefinitely.

If you use Workbox's precaching, that revalidation is efficient, in that the browser only needs to make a single request for your generated `service-worker.js` file, and that response serves as the source of truth for whether anything precached actually changed. Assuming your precached assets don't change *that* frequently, the majority of the time your `service-worker.js` will be identical to the last time it was retrieved, and there won't be any further bandwidth or CPU cycles used on updating.

If you use runtime caching with a stale-while-revalidate policy for everything, then that "while-revalidate" step happens for each and every response. You'll get the "stale" response back to the page almost immediately, so your overall performance should still be good, but you're incurring extra requests made by your service worker "in the background" to re-fetch each URL, and update the cache. There's an increase in bandwidth and CPU cycles used in this approach.

Apart from using additional resources, another reason you might prefer precaching to stale-while-revalidate is that you can populate your full cache ahead of time, without having to wait for the first time they're accessed. If there are certain assets that are only used on a subsection of your web app, and you'd like those assets to be cached ahead of time, that would be trickier to do if you're only doing runtime caching.

And one more advantage offered by precaching is that it will update your cache *en masse*. This helps avoid scenarios where, e.g., one JavaScript file was updated by virtue of being requested on a previous page, but then when you navigate to the next page, the newer JavaScript isn't compatible with the DOM provided by your stale HTML. Precaching everything reduces the chances of these versioning mismatches from happening. ([Especially if you do *not* enable `skipWaiting`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#skip_the_waiting_phase).)

Comment: "_another reason you might prefer precaching to stale-while-revalidate is that you can populate your full cache ahead of time, without having to wait for the first time they're accessed_". That would require downloading X data so I assume precaching everything is not recommended if you wanna minimize the amount of data being downloaded at first visit?

Comment: Yup. It's a tradeoff.